# How could I set the number of Android original desktops?

Tags: settings, home-screen

Android has 5 original desktop on my phone, I couldn't delete one of them. How could I set the number of desktop?

Comment: That depends on the "launcher" you are using. So as long you didn't install a launcher from the Playstore you can name, it would be helpful if you updated your question with some more details: what device you have, what Android version you are running. This way people knowing the device might be able to help you. -- for a start: you might try to pinch your homescreen (tap it with two fingers, pinch them together). On some homescreens this brings an overview, where you can add/delete screens.